# Avalonia Binding Visibility to property dependent on other property

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm new to **Avalonia** and studying it without solid experience with WPF.

I encountered with next situation: I have property which returns `bool` by comparison of other property value to specific (constant) value. Button command changes this second property, but first (`bool`) binds only one time, disregards to specifying `OneWay` binding, not `OneTime`.

```
<Button Content="..."
            IsVisible="{Binding EndButtonVisible, 
                        Mode=OneWay}"
            Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private WorkDayState _currentDayState = WorkDayState.Ended;
    public WorkDayState CurrentDayState { get => _currentDayState; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _currentDayState, value); }
    public bool EndButtonVisible => CurrentDayState == WorkDayState.Ended;

    public void ChangeStateCommand()
    {
        WorkDayState newState;
        switch (CurrentDayState)
        {
            case WorkDayState.Suspended:
            case WorkDayState.Ended:
            default:
                newState = WorkDayState.Started; break;
            case WorkDayState.Started:
                newState = WorkDayState.Suspended; break;
        }
        CurrentDayState = newState;
    }
}
```

The question is how to force `OneWay` binding to work with computed property?

Comment: You need to raise an event when a property changes, so that the UI will know it needs to update. Take a look at this: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/concepts/reactiveui/reactive-view-model (Assuming `ViewModelBase` is derived from `ReactiveObject`.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found next solution, based on custom converters:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Salary.Views.Converters;assembly=Salary">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:WorkDayStateToBooleanConverter x:Key="currentDayStateEquals"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Content="..."
            IsVisible="{Binding CurrentDayState, 
                        Mode=OneWay,
                        Converter={StaticResource currentDayStateEquals}, 
                        ConverterParameter=Suspended}"
            Command="{Binding ChangeStateCommand}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

And converter itself:

```
public class EnumEqualsStringToBooleanConverter<TEnum> : IValueConverter
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public object Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isEnum = value != null &&
            value is TEnum;
        if (isEnum &&
            parameter != null &&
            Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(value.ToString(), out var enumValue))
        {
            var enumParameters = parameter.ToString().Trim('\'').Split(',').Select(str =>
            {
                if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(str, out var enumParameter))
                {
                    return (TEnum?)enumParameter;
                }

                return null;
            });

            return enumParameters.Any(enumParameter => enumValue.Equals(enumParameter));
        }

        // converter used for the wrong type
        return new BindingNotification(new InvalidCastException(), BindingErrorType.Error);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BindingNotification(new NotSupportedException(), BindingErrorType.Error);
    }
}
```

Based on generic enum comparison converter I created concrete:

```
public class WorkDayStateToBooleanConverter: EnumEqualsStringToBooleanConverter<WorkDayState>
{
}
```

Of course, it will be better to use generic parameters, but I didn't found and information on this topic at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with refreshing the value of `EndButtonVisible` property is caused by lack of property change notification, not by the binding mode. If you add the line below at the end of your `ChangeStateCommand` function it should work as expected.

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EndButtonVisible));
```

It will notify the view that this property has changed and the binding will be refreshed. Note that you have to inherit from `ReactiveObject` in order to use this function.